# JavaScript inherit DOM property to all objects and following

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If i change the innerHTML property to the document.documentElement

```
document.documentElement.__defineSetter__("innerHTML", function() { ... });
```

How to inherit this new setter to all child objects and the objects subsequently created in the DOM?

Comment: Have you tried `HTMLElement.prototype.innerHTML`? Documentation can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.

Comment: Don't mess with the DOM! What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'd add my own method instead of replacing the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to alter the `innerHTML` property on the `Element` prototype to have it take effect on all instances in the DOM.

This is somewhat ill advised though, as you'll most certainly end up breaking some core functionality of the DOM API.

Instead of directly changing `innerHTML`, you could create your own property that cloaks the original. If you *really* want to mess with standard DOM API, you should be able to figure out how from the first example.

Setter:

- [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
function innerHTMLEvent () {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
}

Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'innerHTMLWithEvent', {
  set: function (v) {
    this.innerHTML = v;
    innerHTMLEvent.call(this);
  }
});
document.getElementById('thing').innerHTMLWithEvent = 'Yo.';
```

```html
<div id="thing"></div>
```

Method (more flexible):

```js
function innerHTMLEvent () {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
}

if (!Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty('innerHTMLWithEvent')) {
  Element.prototype.innerHTMLWithEvent = function (v, fn) {
    this.innerHTML = v;
    fn.call(this);
  };
}

document.getElementById('thing').innerHTMLWithEvent('Yo.', innerHTMLEvent);
```

```html
<div id="thing"></div>
```

It should also be noted that `__defineSetter__` is both non-standard and deprecated. A rare double occurrence of reasons not to use it.

Comment: when i use __defineSetter__ it works but when i use Object.defineProperty it throw an to much recursion error, why?

Comment: If you've overwritten `innerHTML` with `Object.defineProperty` then you've destroyed the original functionality. Trying to use `innerHTML` inside the setter method will cause infinite recursion. This is why you typically don't want to mess with the DOM API, some functionality becomes very hard to recreate.